# Google Maps API или Яндекс Карты API

Tags: карты, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте. Появилась необходимость разместить на сайте карту для прокладки маршрута между городами. Маршрут должен отображаться на карте, по нему вычисляться расстояние + нужно получать основные промежуточные точки маршрута - также для отображения на карте. Почитал google API. Маршрут прокладывается, но не могу получить данные о промежуточных точках. Выводятся данные по том, где повернуть и т.д., но названия городов по пути - нет. Кто-нибудь, возможно, сталкивался с такой проблемой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли реализовать это средствами google map, и если да, то как? Или может быть Яндекс карты?

Answer (score 0):

НЯП гуглдиректионс АПИ, маршрут - есть объект Directions Routes, который содержит в себе Directions Legs, у которого в свою очередь, есть массив объектов Directions Steps, и где-то в этой связке прячутся промежуточные точки маршрута с геокодированием.

рекомендую пробежаться по этой связке объектов и поискать, у меня когда-то была похожая задача, но не помню где я нашел адреса.

Comment: Я смотрел, но там нет информации о городах, которые проезжаешь. Там хранится информация типа: повернуть налево, .... Читаю Яндекс API, но тоже не нахожу нужного. Как бы не пришлось в БД создавать граф с маршрутами городов России))

Comment: а вот в объекте diretctions-steps есть такое поле: 
start_location contains the geocoded LatLng of the starting point of this step.
может, оно?..

Comment: Я такого не нахожу у себя. У Вас есть icq или скайп - так быстрее будет..

Comment: Почитал описание на google. Похоже там хранятся координаты тех самых точек, которые я описывал выше: точки поворота и т.д... в Яндексе тоже нет такого похоже(

Comment: API маршрутов - это платное API.

Answer (score 0):

У Яндекса покрытие России более подробное, другой вопрос, API, приложение частенько перестает работать из-за апгрейда версии, т.е. хромает обратная совместимость